# Laravel - PHP - Unable to toggle two forms in a single view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, forms, laravel-controller

I have a single view `dashboard.blade.php`.

It's having multiple forms. I have set the data attribute `data-toggle='collapse` in an `<a>` element.

This is working properly for a single form when using the **keyboard arrow down** method.

When click on that `arrow` again, the first form will hide from the view.

However, when I click on second `<a>`, whilst first form is already opened, both forms are displaying simultaneously.

I need to manage this to display **one** form at a time and **hide** another form by clicking on next form.

Below is my code (`dashboard.blade.php`).

**First form**:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse"
               data-parent="#accordion3"
               href="#collapseTwo3"
               aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="collapseTwo3"
               data-expandable="false"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm pmd-accordion-icon-left">toys</i>Brands
                <i class="material-icons md-dark pmd-sm pmd-accordion-arrow">keyboard_arrow_down</i></a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal"
                  method="post"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data"
                  action="{{ url('importBrands') }}">

                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group files">
                    <label>Upload Your File</label>
                    <input type="file" name="import_file" />
                </div>
                <div align="right">
                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary">Export</button> -->
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Import</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Second form**:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse"
               data-parent="#accordion3"
               href="#collapseThree3"
               aria-expanded="false"
               aria-controls="collapseThree3"
               data-expandable="false"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm pmd-accordion-icon-left">category</i>Categories
                <i class="material-icons md-dark pmd-sm pmd-accordion-arrow">keyboard_arrow_down</i></a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal"
                  method="post"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data"
                  action="{{ url('importCategories') }}">

                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group files">
                    <label>Upload Your File</label>
                    <input type="file" name="import_file" />
                </div>
                <div align="right">
                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary">Export</button> -->
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Import</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**material.js**

```
var FloatingLabel = function ($$$1) {
    // constants >>>
    var DATA_KEY = 'md.floatinglabel';
    var EVENT_KEY = "." + DATA_KEY;
    var NAME = 'floatinglabel';
    var NO_CONFLICT = $$$1.fn[NAME];
    var ClassName = {
      IS_FOCUSED: 'is-focused',
      HAS_VALUE: 'has-value'
    };
    var Event = {
      CHANGE: "change" + EVENT_KEY,
      FOCUSIN: "focusin" + EVENT_KEY,
      FOCUSOUT: "focusout" + EVENT_KEY
    };
    var Selector = {
      DATA_PARENT: '.floating-label',
      DATA_TOGGLE: '.floating-label .custom-select, .floating-label .form-control' // <<< constants

    };

    var FloatingLabel =
    /*#__PURE__*/
    function () {
      function FloatingLabel(element) {
        this._element = element;
        this._parent = $$$1(element).closest(Selector.DATA_PARENT)[0];
      }

      var _proto = FloatingLabel.prototype;

      _proto.change = function change() {
        if ($$$1(this._element).val() || $$$1(this._element).is('select') && $$$1('option:first-child', $$$1(this._element)).html().replace(' ', '') !== '') {
          $$$1(this._parent).addClass(ClassName.HAS_VALUE);
        } else {
          $$$1(this._parent).removeClass(ClassName.HAS_VALUE);
        }
      };

      _proto.focusin = function focusin() {
        $$$1(this._parent).addClass(ClassName.IS_FOCUSED);
      };

      _proto.focusout = function focusout() {
        $$$1(this._parent).removeClass(ClassName.IS_FOCUSED);
      };

      FloatingLabel._jQueryInterface = function _jQueryInterface(event) {
        return this.each(function () {
          var _event = event ? event : 'change';

          var data = $$$1(this).data(DATA_KEY);

          if (!data) {
            data = new FloatingLabel(this);
            $$$1(this).data(DATA_KEY, data);
          }

          if (typeof _event === 'string') {
            if (typeof data[_event] === 'undefined') {
              throw new Error("No method named \"" + _event + "\"");
            }

            data[_event]();
          }
        });
      };

      return FloatingLabel;
    }();

    $$$1(document).on(Event.CHANGE + " " + Event.FOCUSIN + " " + Event.FOCUSOUT, Selector.DATA_TOGGLE, function (event) {
      FloatingLabel._jQueryInterface.call($$$1(this), event.type);
    });
    $$$1.fn[NAME] = FloatingLabel._jQueryInterface;
    $$$1.fn[NAME].Constructor = FloatingLabel;

    $$$1.fn[NAME].noConflict = function () {
      $$$1.fn[NAME] = NO_CONFLICT;
      return FloatingLabel._jQueryInterface;
    };

    return FloatingLabel;
  }($);
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're handling that with Javascript? If yes, then add that code.

Answer (score 0):

> I think, you forget the add the few lines in your code.( Adding Some Line in Your Code)

```
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3">
        paste your code here
   </div>
```

> Simple solution using Bootstraps framework.(Full Example)

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body"> First Form Html </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body"> Second Form Html </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body"> Third Form Html </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Raman. It worked for me. But multiple column forms should have more updates.